# target encoding h2o - How to apply to new data

Tags: r, h2o

i'm using h2o to build a classification model and I observed that target encoding of my categorical variables with high cardinality helps to improve performance ( lower false positive).

I'm using R api, and as the doc specfied http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/target-encoding.html i created the mapping with `h2o.target_encode_fit` and apply to train, test and validation with `h2o.target_encode_transform`.

Now I'd like to put my model in production.

From the documentation of `h2o.target_encode_transform` it seems that the `y` arg of the function is mandatory. But in production phase I don't know my target variable.

Can I safely apply the encoding of the training to the new data? 
In absence of any other alternative I'd extract from my training dataframe categorical columns along with encoding , then join on new data on categorical columns.

Hope I was clear enough.